# Past Perfect And Present Perfect In One Sentence

Tags: past-perfect

> ==> Until more recently, Product XYZ had not been ready but Provider XYZ has made changes to the product a while ago that address the issue and
>   markets are now embracing the product.

Is this sentence grammatically correct? My thinking was:

- 1) Had not been / past perfect --> It is ready ever since Provider
  XYZ has released the product but since that was a while ago its a
  condition that changed in the past before the present.
- 2) Has been /present perfect --> Provider XYZ released a product but
  this release is affecting the present and future and I want to
  underline that by using present perfect. I also don't know the exact moment when they released it.

Thank you for your help, much appreciated. Just wanted to make sure I am using past perfect correctly. At what point would you use "past tense" in a sentence like this? E.g. if you know exactly when the product was released.

Comment: Thank you for linking to the question but in the other question the person is not using present perfect, only present tense, so this is not a duplicate in my opinion

Comment: It addresses the same (non-)issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no prohibition on using the *past perfect* and the *present perfect* in one statement. For example:

> Until more recently, Product XYZ *had* not been ready but Provider XYZ
>   *has* now made changes to the product ... .

The problem here lies in the combination of a present tense (the *present perfect*) with an adjunct of past or finished time (*a while ago*). This is generally ungrammatical. For example:

> *Until more recently, Product XYZ had not been ready but *last week* Provider XYZ has made changes to the product ... .
>
> *Until more recently, Product XYZ had not been ready but *in 2014* Provider XYZ has made changes to the product ... .

While some native speakers might find your original sentence marginally acceptable, you are safer using the past tense (*preterite*):

> Until more recently, Product XYZ had not been ready but  Provider XYZ
>   made changes to the product a while ago that address the issue and markets are now embracing the product.

And if the issue no longer exists, you could put '*address*' into the past tense also.

Alternatively, you can replace the past time adjunct with one that extends time into the present and retain the *present perfect*:

> Until more recently, Product XYZ had not been ready but  Provider XYZ has
>   made changes to the product *in the past few months* that address the issue and markets are now embracing the product.

Comment: I like the alternative, thank you very much for providing so many examples.

Answer (score 1):

The distance is time is too large and unjustified. Use the simple past:

*Until recently, Product XYZ **was not** ready but Provider XYZ **has made** changes to the product a while ago.*

especially as there are no simple past verbs to make for a smoother transition.

Your version is possible, but not preferred. E.g., at Google Books:

**"until recently it had not been" "has been"**
About 3,220 results

**"until recently it was not" "has been"**
About 64,400 results